# SOQL on a custom object returns 0 records but Storage Usage UI shows a lot of Data Storage?

Tags: soql, data-storage

We just created a full copy sandbox and are attempting to clear space in it to fall below limits. As you can see in the screenshot below, Analytics - which is a custom object (`Analytics__c`) - is taking up over 661GB of data storage space. However, a SOQL on Analytics__c returns 0 records!? The object in Production certainly has (a lot of) records.

Tried `Export`, `Export All` option in Data Loader, `ALL ROWS` via Developer Console and Workbench without luck. Recycle Bin has about 5 million rows (from a different clearing exercise on Attachment to reduce File Storage), but none are related to the custom object in question.

We don't want to delete ALL the records in that object, just enough so we are under the limits, so deleting and re-creating that object is not an option.

I am out of ideas. Can you folks share your thoughts please?

[image]

[image]

Comment: Sometimes it takes few hours to have stats to be updated on that page, especially on big orgs. In case if that does not occur -- probably you would need to log a case with support

Comment: By ‘stats’ do you mean the values reported by Storage Usage screen? If so, I wanted to clarify that Analytics custom object does have 660GB worth of records at the moment. The question is, why does SOQL return 0 records? Production has records and this is a full-copy sandbox.

Comment: It's a bit obvious, but did you check your user have visibility on those data? When did you finished created your sandbox?